# What's wrong with my constructor for this stack as array implementation?

Tags: c++, constructor, stack

what is wrong with my constructor below? I am getting an error that says:

Error   1   error C2359:  member of non-class type requires single initializer expression
Error   2   error C2359:  member of non-class type requires single initializer expression

It says the error is at line 55, which I made the font bold below if you take a quick look.

```
template <typename Type>
class Drop_off_stack_as_array {
    private:
        int itop;
        int ibottom;
        int entry_count;
        int array_capacity;
        Type *array;

    public:
        Drop_off_stack_as_array( int = 10 );
        Drop_off_stack_as_array( Drop_off_stack_as_array const & );
        ~Drop_off_stack_as_array();

        int size() const;
        bool empty() const;
        Type top() const;
        bool full() const; 

        void swap( Drop_off_stack_as_array & );
        Drop_off_stack_as_array &operator = ( Drop_off_stack_as_array );
        void push( Type const & );
        Type pop();
        void clear();

    template <typename T>
    friend std::ostream &operator << ( std::ostream &, Drop_off_stack_as_array<T> const & );
};

template <typename Type>
Drop_off_stack_as_array<Type>::Drop_off_stack_as_array( int n ):
    itop(0),
    ibottom(0),
    entry_count(0),
    array_capacity(0,n),
    **array(new Type[array_capacity]){**
        //empty constructor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is one line earlier, here:

```
array_capacity(0,n),
```

should be

```
array_capacity(n),
```